# Colspan not working in pure HTML, no CSS, applied to th/td, equally in each row

Tags: html, html-table

I cannot figure out why my `colspan` isn't working. I have a CSS solution, but I am just baffled why this wouldn't work. **The First column should be 1/3 the width of the other columns with colspan="1" on the first th and td, while all others have colspan="3".**

The application is for a leaderboard, so the first column will contain the rank number (1, 2, 3...) and needs to be much more narrow than the subsequent columns.

Of course, it can be solved with `class="colspan-3"` and `class="colspan-1"` along with the css `colspan-1{width:4.5%} colspan-3{width:13.5%}` or whatever the math works out to... but again, I really just want to know what's up.

To add details, because I think this question will help someone in the future:

At the time, I thought i could use colspan as a relative unit, essentially, by making each column's width relative to the other columns. The issue I was having was that each column had the exact same unit in it all the way down. It only really works for a single cell in a column, essentially like the "merge" function in Microsoft Excel.

```html
<table border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">th1 colspan1</th><!-- colspan=1 here -->
      <th colspan="3">th2 colspan3</th>
      <th colspan="3">th3 colspan3</th>
      <th colspan="3">th4 colspan3</th>
      <th colspan="3">th5 colspan3</th>
      <th colspan="3">th6 colspan3</th>
      <th colspan="3">th7 colspan3</th>
      <th colspan="3">th8 colspan3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="1">td1 colspan1</td><!-- colspan=1 here -->
      <td colspan="3">td2 colspan3</td>
      <td colspan="3">td3 colspan3</td>
      <td colspan="3">td4 colspan3</td>
      <td colspan="3">td5 colspan3</td>
      <td colspan="3">td6 colspan3</td>
      <td colspan="3">td7 colspan3</td>
      <td colspan="3">td8 colspan3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: A photo of the table in question, showing the widths of each cell is the same regardless of the colspan declaration.]

Comment: What's the end result goal? If the table's rows have the same number of cells, why do you need colspan?

Comment: @j08691 Sorry if it's not apparent, I'll highlight it in the post but the first column should be 1/3 of the other columns

Comment: `colspan` doesn't change the width of a column, it changes how many columns a cell covers. If all the cells in a given column have the same `colspan`, it will act like just one column as there aren't really any columns to span. See: `colspan` in the [`td`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) reference. If you want relative widths, you're probably better off with `display:grid` rather than using a table.

Comment: I suggest a perusal of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics.

Comment: @Ouroborus amazing. Thank you so much, I thought I was going nuts just reading and re-reading the same definitions of colspan and clearly I missed that. Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ouroborus, I thought I was going nuts but after nearly a decade of using HTML every day apparently there are still things to be learned.

colspan won't work if all cells in a column are set to the same number of columns to span, as defined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Thanks again to Ouroborus for catching my misunderstanding!